# css grid-template-rows doesn't work as expected (size doesn't change with fr)

Tags: html, css, canvas, css-grid

I want to place 5 x 5 canvas in a div and position them with css grid with a buffer on top/bottom. Here is what i tryed:

This is how they are palced:

```
 <div class="main"> 
      <div class="imgDiv" grid-column-start="1" grid-row-start="2";>
           <canvas class="canvas">
      </div>
      <div class="imgDiv" grid-column-start="1" grid-row-start="3">
           <canvas class="canvas">
      </div>
  ...    
 </div>
```

css main:

```
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 5.61671fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 5.61671fr; // 5.616 is the buffer
 display: grid;

 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-y: auto;

 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
```

canvas:

```
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: fill;

 margin: 0%;
 padding: 0%;
```

imgDiv:

```
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
```

So what i noticed and what i don't understand is that the height of my canvas doesn't change if i increase the buffer to for example 10fr.

I think it has somthing to do with object-fit: cover / object-fit: fit.
What do i have to change, so that if the buffer gets bigger the width of the canvas gets smaler while still showing the howl image?

tyvm

Comment: You want your canvas to take 5x5 ? But then why do you set their container smaller than that ? And how would you like that canvas be ? Next to each other or below ?

Comment: I want to place 25 canvas in my main div. 5 rows, 5 cols all next to each other but with a buffer (empty space) on top of them and below

Comment: their proportions should be depending on the buffer. big buffer => small height,
width = div.width / 5

Comment: ok so your html is like 25 `imgDiv` with different setting and a buffer over and below. so basicaly your grid is 7 row by 5 columns, as 1st and last column would be buffer ?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved now. The main problem turned out to be that i had to adjust the width/height of my canvas as well as adjusting my grid-templates. For some reason my browser didn't allow my canvas to get "pressed" into proportions below about w/h of: 2:1

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use grid-template:

```css
  grid-template:
    "b1 b1 b1 b1 b1"
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    "b2 b2 b2 b2 b2";
```

### DEMO

```css
.main{
  /*grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5.61671fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 5.61671fr; /* 5.616 is the buffer*/
  grid-template:
    "b1 b1 b1 b1 b1"
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    ". . . . ."
    "b2 b2 b2 b2 b2";
  display: grid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: fill;
   margin: 0%;
   padding: 0%;
}
.imgDiv{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}
/* ADDED */
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(2) canvas{
  background:red;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(3) canvas{
  background:blue;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(4) canvas{
  background:orange;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(5) canvas{
  background:purple;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(6) canvas{
  background:pink;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(7) canvas{
  background:pink;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(8) canvas{
  background:purple;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(9) canvas{
  background:yellow;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(10) canvas{
  background:pink;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(11) canvas{
  background:red;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(12) canvas{
  background:blue;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(13) canvas{
  background:red;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(14) canvas{
  background:purple;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(15) canvas{
  background:orange;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(16) canvas{
  background:blue;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(17) canvas{
  background:red;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(18) canvas{
  background:blue;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(19) canvas{
  background:orange;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(20) canvas{
  background:purple;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(21) canvas{
  background:pink;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(22) canvas{
  background:pink;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(23) canvas{
  background:red;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(24) canvas{
  background:blue;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(25) canvas{
  background:orange;
}
.imgDiv:nth-of-type(26) canvas{
  background:yellow;
}

.buff-1, .buff-2{
  height: 50px;
  background: salmon;
}
.buff-1{
  grid-area:b1;
}
.buff-2{
  grid-area:b2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="buff-1"></div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
       <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDiv">
     <canvas class="canvas"/>
  </div>
  <div class="buff-2"></div>
 </div>
```